# os.Wait() does not wait for program termination in golang

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, process

At some point throughout my code execution, I want my program to start an editor (doesn't matter which one) for the user to perform some live editing.

I need my program to halt at this point and until the user decides to close the editor (more or less how git rebase works)

Here is how I go about this

```
func main() {
    fpath := os.TempDir() + "/afile.txt"
    f, err := os.Create(fpath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/local/bin/code", fpath)
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

No error is ever printed, however the above code, although it does of course open `vscode`, it terminates (returns) before the user closes the editor.

Shouldn't `cmd.Wait()` be handling this?

The program is executed on MacOS Catalina fwiw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't cmd.Wait() be handling this?

Yes, and it does. Go waits as intended, it's your invocation of `/usr/local/bin/code` which is incorrect, and does not wait. The default behavior of `code` is to exit immediately after spawning the VSCode window. It does not wait for the window to close, and so Go cannot wait for the window to close.

Try simply typing `code` in your terminal. You'll find that it exits immediately, even thought your VSCode window is still open.

To make `code` block until the editor window is closed (thereby allowing Go to wait), you need to pass the `-w` or `--wait` flag to it. Again, try `code -w` in your terminal. You'll find the terminal command blocks until the VSCode window is closed.

Practically, you only need to change this...

```
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/local/bin/code", fpath)
```

to this:

```
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/local/bin/code", "-w", fpath)
    // or
    // cmd := exec.Command("/usr/local/bin/code", "--wait", fpath)
```

Answer (score -3):

As per https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start

> Start starts the specified command but does not wait for it to
> complete.
>
> If Start returns successfully, the c.Process field will be set.
>
> The Wait method will return the exit code and release associated
> resources once the command exits.

If you could `strace code` you'll find `+++ exited with 0 +++` at the bottom, in linux.

Basically, the command that starts vscode exits, `clones` (a type of fork) and thus doesn't wait to return.

`strace code -w` actually waits for vscode to exit.